# Where can I find Investopedia data set for download?

Tags: data-request, nlp

I want to train a NLP model based on [investopedia](https://www.investopedia.com/) data set but I am not able to find it.

Comment: more information please....what is investopedia?

Comment: Investopedia is an American website based in New York City that focuses on investing and finance education along with reviews, ratings and comparisons of various financial products such as brokerage accounts. - from wikipedia

Comment: Any progress on this?

Comment: nope, did not find it.